# How to derive Poisson Distribution from Binomial Distribution?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

I am familiar with another answer about this topic: [How to prove Poisson Distribution is the approximation of Binomial Distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795049/how-to-prove-poisson-distribution-is-the-approximation-of-binomial-distribution) , but i don't understand one part of it.

Could anyone explain to me the following part;

For $i$ fixed and $n$ large we have
$$
\frac{n!}{n^i \cdot (n-i)!} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot \ldots \cdot (n-i+1) }{ n^i} \approx 1
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\require{cancel}\dfrac{n!}{n^i(n-i)!}=\dfrac{\cancel{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-i)}\cdot\overbrace{(n-i+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot (n-2)\cdot (n-1)\cdot n}^i}{\cancel{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-i)}\cdot \underbrace{n\cdot n\cdot\ldots\cdot n}_i}=$$ 
$$=\dfrac{n}{n}\cdot \dfrac{n-1}{n}\cdot\dfrac{n-2}n\cdot\ldots\cdot\dfrac{n-i+1}{n}\to 1 \text{ as } n\to\infty.$$
Last expression contains the product of $i$ fractions. Each of these fractions converges to $1$ as $n\to\infty$. Number of factors is fixed, so the limit of a product equals to the product of limits.

Comment: +1 The bit about "numbers of factors is fixed" is essential; otherwise one could wrongly conclude that $n!/n^n \to 1$